How to create handlebars in Superset and avoid error call to Function() blocked by CSP?
I got Superset 4.0.0, installed with Docker.
I don't change any setting of Superset.
I create Handlebars, add dimensions, metrics.

But I get error:
call to Function() blocked by CSP

I think I need edit setting of Superset,but I'm not sure.
How to avoid this error?

As far as I can tell, you would have to set the Content Security Policy to allow unsafe-eval, which is bad practice. This is a known issue with Handlebars: https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/1443
